# High performance computing projects using Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, hpc

For a paper I want to argue why I have used Python for the implementation of my algorithm. Besides the typical arguments that it is fast -using suitable libraries- and it is easy to implement the algorithm with it, I thought maybe there are some big HPC projects that are using it.

Does anyone know a famous project that uses Python for large parallel calculations, maybe with a paper which I can cite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, as great a language as python is, it wouldn't be a suitable environment for scientific computing and in particular high performance computing, if those libraries weren't available. So you can see python as one pieces of a larger puzzle - much as MATLAB can be.

The two key reasons to use python for scientific or high-performance computing can then be said to be because of the convenient interfaces to software packages written in other languages, or because you need fast turn around on a project. Commonly, both issues arise at the time.

The classic example of this is the paper ["Feeding a Large-scale Physics Application to Python"](http://www.swig.org/papers/Py97/beazley.html), by [David M. Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/) which combines performance intensive C++ with python using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

If you're looking for something very current, there is a new paper, ["A New Modelling System for Seasonal Streamflow Forecasting Service of the Bureau of Meteorology, Australia"](http://www.mssanz.org.au/modsim2011/rego/index.php/MODSIM2011/MODSIM2011Perth/paper/view/35), by [Daehyok Shin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242062/daehyok-shin) et al., that due to be presented at MODSIM2011. I saw the first author speak at the [Melbourne Python Users Group](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MelbournePUG) about how [ipython](http://ipython.org/) was used being used as a mechanism for bridging high performance fortran models and HDF5 data in such a way that even non-programmers could make effective contributions to a larger scientific program.

Comment: Great answer! This was exactly I was searching for.

Comment: @Andrew Walker Have you heard of OpenStack ? The most popular Opensource Complete cloud stack and Surprisingly it is written in python. www.openstack.org

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Python success stories](http://www.python.org/about/success/) page on Python.org.

Comment: These are packages which can be used for scientific computing but not scientific projects that use Python to calculate a real world problem.

Comment: Misread your question a little. I've revised my answer, and included a link I think you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/%20Blender) is written in Python which is quite impressive for what it can do. If you're not impressed by testing it, you should watch some of the shorts people have made using it. Not as impressive, Ubuntu Software Center and BitTorrent are written in Python. Battlefield 2 uses a good chunk of Python

Comment: Blender is written in C. It does have a Python API though, for writing plugins and the like.

Comment: Ah, must have misread something a while back.

Comment: It *could* work as an answer, but seeing as it's used as their plugin system, it might be harder to get away with it. Many projects definitely use Python though. :)